# Optimize grouping of list of lists by elements

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, pattern-matching, gathering

I have a sorted list of lists of size ~200,000 x 3. The data are such that the first element of each triplet loops through i = 1, 1.1, 1.2, ..., 199.9, 200, and for every value of i, the second element loops through all integer values 0-99, inclusive. The third elements are the real "data". I want to group every 100 triplets for each value of i to perform operations like `Total` and `Min` on the third elements; i.e. to do:

```
Total[{{i,0,data0},{i,1,data1},...,{i,99,data99}}][[3]]/100
```

for every value of i. The problem is that my data set is missing some points, and sometimes there aren't 100 triplets for each i.

I want my final output to look like:

> { {1, data1}, {1.1, data2}, {1.2, data3}, ..., {199.9, data1990}, {200, data1991} }

so I can plot them. If my data set was complete, I would simply use `Table` and iterate in steps of 100, performing `Total` and `Min` on every 100 elements. However, this won't work here so I tried two other approaches. They both get me the desired output, but the problem is that both are abysmally slow (~10min evaluation times). How might I optimize either of these attempts? Or, what is a better way to do this?

My data set is called `testVCdata`.

## **ATTEMPT 1 (`Position`)**

```
averagesTEST = Table[
   {1 + i/10 // N, 
    Total@joinByCoup[1 + i/10 // N]/Length@positions[1 + i/10 // N]},
   {i, 0, 1990}];
minsTEST = Table[
   {1 + i/10 // N, Min@joinByCoup[1 + i/10 // N]},
   {i, 0, 1990}];

positions[i_] := Position[testVCdata, {i, _, _}]
joinByCoup[i_] := 
 testVCdata[[positions[i][[1, 1]] ;; positions[i][[-1, 1]], 3]]
```

## **ATTEMPT 2 (`GroupBy`)**

```
averagesTEST = Table[
   {1 + i/10 // N, 
    Total@GroupBy[testVCdata, First][[i, All, 3]]/
     Length@GroupBy[testVCdata, First][[i]]}
   , {i, 0, 1990}];
minsTEST = Table[
   {1 + i/10 // N, Min@GroupBy[testVCdata, First][[i, All, 3]]}
   , {i, 0, 1990}];
```

Apologies in advance for clarity or formatting issues. I am quite new to SE so please let me know if there is something I should fix, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. A concrete **minimal** example will get more focused responses. Consider `tab = Table[{i, j, RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 3]}, {j, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 2, 
   0.1}]`. Give us a table of this size to work with. Is it flattened as well? Choose other values and rearrange it to make it similar to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please verify that `Map[Last,Map[Total,Split[testVCdata,#1[[2]]<#2[[2]]&]]]` correctly totals each run of items. Please report how long this takes to run. I'm guessing WAY LESS than 10 minutes! That does depend on there not being so many missing items that the test I've written to detect the end of a run does not fail. If the result of this is incorrect then please tell me enough about the test case so that I can reproduce the failure here. Thanks

Comment: @Bill thank you so much! When used in conjunction with Thread and a Table to generate the "i" values, your solution is nearly instantaneous and gives the desired output. In order to use it with `Min` in place of `Total`, I changed it to this: `Map[Min,Split[testVCdata, #1[[2]]<#2[[2]]&][[All, All, 3]]]`. If you would like to post as a solution I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: Only `nearly?`, I need to do better than that `;}` Given `testVCdata` of the form `{i,j,data}` are you looking for the `mean` and `min` for each value of `i` or for each value of `j`?  Are your `i` values decimals like in your description or are they rationals like in your code? Do you want to present the i or j along with the mean or min? or just the mean or min?

Comment: @Bill given `testVCdata` of form `{i,j,data}`, I am looking for the `Mean` and `Min` of `data` over all `j` values that are associated with each `i` value, i.e. each value of `i` has a single mean and min value. My `i` values are decimals - I originally generated them with rationals and then appended `//N` to match the data set. This question is for the purpose of presenting means/mins alongside `i` values. I use `j` values for something else

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. that helps. Decimal values can display identically, but differ in a few bottom bits, not be ==. Rationals won't do that. Maybe doesn't matter. If `testVCdata` is sorted on `i` try `Map[{#[[1,1]],Mean[#[[All,3]]],Min[#[[All,3]]]}&,SplitBy[testVCdata,First]]` The `SplitBy` should divide `testVCdata` into groups with the same `i`, `#[[1,1]]` should extract an `i`, `Mean[#[[All,3]]]` should find the mean of the group, `Min[#[[All,3]]]` will find the min of the group,. `Map` should do this for all groups. Test this VERY carefully on LOTS of examples.

Comment: @Bill beautiful, thank you so much!